# _.template render result is a function not a String in node js

Tags: node.js, underscore.js

I'm using underscore js as a module in my express 4 application. I use the template function but the result returns a function object instead of a rendered String. I Finnally solved this by updating my package.json to "underscore": "~1.6.0" instead of "underscore": "^1.6.0". Is there any major change on how to use template function in underscorejs version 1.6.0 above or it's just a bug ? thanks in advance

Comment: an example? how do you use it? sounds like `_.template` instead of `_.template()`

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bug, but underscore 1.7.0 introduced lots of changes that were not necessarily reflected in the updated minor version.

There were was some discussion about this on this github:

https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/issues/1805